# C++ NTL algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm

I cant seem to find any info on, which algorithms in the NTL C++ libraries are used.

I am especially interested in the algorithms used for:

- Modular square root (SqrRootMod)
- Kernel of matrix over GF(2) (kernel for mat_GF2 objects)
- Greatest common divisor (GCD - this is probably euclids algorithm)
- Modular inverse (InvMod)
- Jacobi symbol (Jacobi)

If anyone can help with this, I am very grateful!

Comment: You could take a loot at the source: http://www.shoup.net/ntl/download.html

Comment: There are no descriptions of the algorithms. I would have to be able to recognize them from the code!

Answer (score 1):

SqrRootMod, InvMod, Jacobi could be found in ZZ.h and ZZ.c. GCD lies in ZZX.h

I believe you can figure everything out by reading the include files in the [examples](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-examples.html) provided on the official website. There are explanations on the algorithms used too.

Comment: GCD lies in  [ZZ.h](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/ZZ.cpp.html) too (official website)